# How do I make my block-editor styles match my front-end styles?

Tags: css, block-editor

**The Problem**

I'm currently working on a personal blog that pulls its styles from my `style.css` file. Because It's a blog, I'm also using the block editor to create blog posts, but I want the block editor to visually match what it'll look like on the front end.

**Steps I've taken.**

1. Ensure my `style.css` file is properly enqueued and all edits to it are reflected on the front end.
2. Created an `editor-style-block-custom.css` file and added it to the project using the following function

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'a-rap-blog-custom-block-editor-styles',
        get_theme_file_uri( "/css/editor-style-block-custom.css" ),
        false, wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ));
} );
```

3. Ensured that my `editor-style-block-custom.css` is enqueued and any edits to it are reflected in my editor. Here I'm using the `.editor-styles-wrapper` class to target elements in the block editor.

**The Question**

How do I create parity between these two style files without doing the double work of editing them both? (i.e. in `style.css` I make `h1 { color: red }` and in `editor.style-block-custom.css` I make `.editor-styles-wrapper h1 { color: red }`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `add_editor_style()` function on the `after_setup_theme()` hook for your editor styles, and enqueue the same style sheet using `wp_enqueue_style()` on the `wp_enqueue_scripts()` hook. Optionally, you can also use `wp_style_add_data()` to inline the styles for better performance.

There's no need to manually add the `.editor-styles-wrapper` class before other selectors if you enqueue the style sheet using the method described above. WordPress will do it for you automatically when you're using this function.

Complete example for a single style sheet:

```php
/**
 * Enqueue editor styles.
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_theme_setup' ) ) :
    function my_theme_setup()  {

        // Enqueue the style sheet in the editor.
        add_editor_style( 'style.css' );
    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup' );
endif;

/**
 * Enqueue front-end styles.
 */
function my_theme_styles() {

    // Enqueue the same style sheet in the front-end.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme', get_theme_file_path( 'style.css' ), [], wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );

    // Inline the contents of the style.css file, if possible.
    wp_style_add_data( 'my-theme', 'path', get_theme_file_path( 'style.css' ) );    
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_styles' );
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I'm running into some trouble because my main style.css file is importing several other css files (one for typography, one settings, one for site structure, as well as a reset, etc.), and using your supplied method makes it so where the imported files can no longer be found. I'm getting a 404 error for these files in my console.

Comment: Using `@import` in your CSS does not work with `add_editor_style()`. You either import them using SCSS/SASS (e.g., `@use 'other-styles';` at the top of the main CSS file) or explicitly add them in the `add_editor_style` call (it accepts an array), if you don't want to use SCSS/SASS.

Comment: `add_editor_style` has nothing whatsoever to do with the block editor. It's for TinyMCE WYSIWYG areas.

Comment: @75thTrombone No, it works just fine in the block editor. Try it.